# Rails: constructing an SQL query to get the number of users created in each week between a start date and an end date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, date

pI am trying to get the number of users created in each week between a start date and '2016-08-15'. This is what I have tried from

http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff

```
    START_DATE = "2016-06-15".freeze


User.where("created_at >= ?",START_DATE).order("created_at")
    .group("TRUNC(DATE_PART('day', '2016-08-15' - START_DATE)/7")
    .count
    .values
```

Without success. I also tried a version suing DATEDIFF but this doesn't appear to work in PG. 
Any help?

EDT: What I am trying to do is to calculate the number of weeks between created_at and start date for each user and group according to that. This will allow me to calculate the number of new users created each week since the start date. From there, I am going sum them to give a cumulative total of user sign-ups by time (in weeks)

EDIT:

Also tried this (using the age function in SQL)

```
     User.order("created_at").group("age(created_at, timestamp '2016-06-5')")
```

But get this error

```
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Comment: Are you missing a parenthesis in group()?

Comment: What do you want as a result?

Answer (score 0):

```
start = '2016-06-15'.to_date.beginning_of_day
ending = '2016-08-15'.to_date.end_of_day
users = User.where("created_at between ? and ?", start, ending)
count = users.size
```

PS. Passing it in with `?` protects you from sql injection.